# Excel pivot table treating money as a string when filtering

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I'm connecting to a data model in Excel and one of my dimensions is a decimal datatype - Excel seems to know this because it sorts it correctly when it's displayed in the pivot table. I can't find a way to filter it as a number, though - when I provide a filter, it treats it like a string instead of a number - setting a  ">= 500" filter gives me numbers that start with 5-9 (like 600, but also 98.3 and 6.2).

The left image shows what the dimension looks like normally - Excel realizes it's a number and not a string, so it sorts it correctly. When I apply a filter (upper right), I get the results below (I've snipped in a few spots so you can see what's missing - I have values from 5-9, then I'm missing 10-49, then have 50-99, missing 100-499, then have 500-999). It shows that Excel is treating it like a string when it filters.

How can I filter this value like the number that it is to get only amounts greater than 500?

[image]

I'm connecting to a SQL Analysis Services model here, but I've confirmed that it has the correct data type in the model. When I use a data table in Excel, this behavior seems inconsistent - sometimes it filters as expected and sometimes not, but I can't figure out how it's deciding.

Comment: Date in Sales order column are Right aligned (Check Scree Shot) so are Number not Text. May be some different reason is creating problem while you Filter !!

Comment: **Cont,,** if the Filter column is A there I can find data are Left aligned (Text),, but Excel doesn't mind while Filter them.